# how to best sort the results of this array

Tags: c++, sorting

This section of code asks for how many elements in an array and then asks for those numbers but I need to sort them in descending order. what is the simplest way to do that?

```
int main()
{
int i=0;
int input=0;
int lowest=0;
int highest=0;
int total=0;
cout << "How many grades do you want to enter?" << endl;
input = validateInt(input);
int *numbers = new int[input];
for(i=0; i < input; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter grade " << i+1 << "." << endl;
    numbers[i] = validateInt(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: By "the simplest way", do you mean a library function?

Comment: You can use: `std::sort(numbers, numbers + input, std::greater<int>());` Docs: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [std::greater](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater).

Comment: Is 'Best' means: O-notation or best usage?

Comment: When efficency gets important to you, you should first analyse your data (number of elements, is the list almost sorted (tends to be the case when user is involved), ...) and think about data structures. if you just have to sort a view elements (like 5 or so) you could even use bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard library and not just for sorting. Use `std::vector` if the number of elements can change or `std::array` if not.For your particular use case you can use what @Galik wrote.

```
    std::sort(numbers, numbers + input, std::greater<int>());
```